# Adding a large timestamp to the current time in Java

Tags: java, timestamp

I am working on an application that supports Google 2-step verification. This application also supports a feature to 'trust this device for 30 days'.

I use a database to save all this information such as IP-addresses and expire times. Now when I fill in the timestamp `System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` to add 30 days to the current time, it inserts a timestamp earlier than the current time into the database.

For example: the current time = `1483223733000 (2016-31-12 11:36 PM UTC+1)`.
Now when I add 30 days (which is `2592000000` milliseconds, it comes to a date similar to `1481520984841 (2016-12-12 6:36 AM UTC+1)` which is not 30 days ahead, but rather about 19 days back in time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem had to do with a 32-bit integer overflow. Since the maximum value for an integer is `2147483647`, 30 days in milliseconds would be too large for an integer and would result in an integer like `-1702967296` (Which is about -19 days in milliseconds.)

To solve this problem, I use a `long` instead of an `int`. So now I do:
`System.currentTimeMillis() + 30L * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;`

Answer (score 2):

You already answered the question of why the calculation is wrong, but I want to recommend you a more idiomatic way to working with dates, if you use Java 8.

1. If you need to add just 30 24-hour-long days (ie. 24 * 30 hours), use:

   ```
   Instant.now().plus(Duration.ofDays(30)).toEpochMilli();
   ```

   or

   ```
   Instant.now().plus(30, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli();
   ```
2. If you need to add exactly 30 days (some days can be 23 or 25 hours long because of daylight saving time etc) according to the current JVM time zone, use:

   ```
   ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).plusDays(30).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
   ```

   or (implicitly use JVM timezone)

   ```
   ZonedDateTime.now().plusDays(30).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Calendar` to do this:

```
    Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    //cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30L * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```